# Appengine Users API: Redirect to create_login_url: 'NoneType' object has no attribute nickname

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I am very new to the App Engine. I want to create user login using the simple users api provided by the google.appengine.api.users module

```
  def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()

    if user:
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        logout = users.create_logout_url('/')

    else:
        self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
        user = users.get_current_user()
        user_name = user.nickname()
```

But it seems that redirection to the login url is not taking place. It shows the error 'NoneType' object has no attribute nickname

What is the problem in my code? If I remove the user.nickname() call under the else clause it's working fine...

Comment: your logic is incorrect. If user, you have a user. Else you don't but then you try to get the current user and then their nickname.

Comment: Yeah! I got the point now. I was on the wrong assumption that, after login, the the program will be redirected to the same state as before. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

Once you perform

```
self.response.write("Redirecting to the login page......")
```

The response is returned to the user. You only get to write one response. So just do the redirect *first* then all the other stuff once you actually get to the desired page.

You don't get to write the response incrementally, it's all or nothing.

Comment: That was a useful information. But the problem is not that. I have edited the question to make my problem more clear..